# Can't understand blank? behaviour on rails object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user object :

```
@user = User.find(1)
```

I just want to make actions if I found user...

```
if @user.present?
  ...
end
```

Development environment (ruby 2.2.1) :

```
@user.present?
# => true
```

Staging environment (ruby 2.2.0) :

```
@user.present?
# => false
@user.nil?
# => false
@user.empty?
# => true
@user.name
# => "Flo"
```

How can my user be empty if I can get his name ? If someone should give me an explanation... Is it a problem with ruby 2.2.0 ?

Thank you !

Comment: in such cases you can simply go with `if @user`

Comment: `@user = User.find(1)` will throw an error if there is no user with id 1.

Comment: If `User.find(1)` does not find an user with that `id` it would raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. Therefore it does not make sense to write any checks for presence like that after a `find` call.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind, is `find(id)` will throw an exception if the ID isn't found.  `find_by_id(id)` will return `nil`, if none is found, so you can safely do the nil check `;)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `acts_as_shopping_cart` completely explains the issue

`present?` is defined as being the opposite of `blank?.`blank?`is defined as whether the object is non-empty, if the object has an`empty?` method or whether the object is non-nil otherwise (see definition [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L17))

This cart gem defined an `empty?` method on the user, so all users with no associated cart items started reporting themselves as empty, and therefore not present.

Comment: Yep... I didn't see this custom empty function... Shame on me... :'( Thank you for you analyse :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, really sorry...
This is not a ruby issue (or may be not totaly).

I installed the "acts_as_shopping_cart" gem (https://github.com/crowdint/acts_as_shopping_cart) and my user was the cart (no information in cart side, all is in cartitems). 
When I removed "acts_as_shopping_cart_using :cart_item" from user model, everything works fine...

Very strange... I removed this gem, developed my own polymorphic cartitem and this is good !

Sorry for that, you didn't have all elements to answer... 
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: cause acts_as_shopping_cart implements an `empty?`method which overload the ActiveRecord method : [acts_as_shopping collection.rb file](https://github.com/crowdint/acts_as_shopping_cart/blob/732375c3819fa6bfca9ada17a29cc496d1b66a15/lib/active_record/acts/shopping_cart/collection.rb)

Comment: You're right Yann !! I didn't see this ! But why this wasn't overload on development environment ?